# undefined method 'change' for :Fixnum when updating Timestamp value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, oauth-2.0, omniauth, google-oauth

I'm using Google's OAuth2 API in a project, using Omniauth to enable creating the initial accounts with little effort, but in order to use the APIs I need to refresh the access_token since they're only valid for an hour, but I'm having an issue updating the expires_at value when I refresh the token.

Here's the code I'm using for requesting the token refresh:

```
require 'oauth2'
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
  def refresh_access_token
    case self.provider
      when "google"
        client = OAuth2::Client.new OAUTH_KEYS_CONFIG['google']['client_id'], 
                                    OAUTH_KEYS_CONFIG['google']['client_secret'],
                                    {
                                      :site => 'https://accounts.google.com',
                                      :authorize_url => "/o/oauth2/auth",
                                      :token_url => "/o/oauth2/token"
                                    }
        response = OAuth2::AccessToken.from_hash(client, :refresh_token => self.refresh_token).refresh!

        self.update_attribute(:access_token, response.token)
        self.update_attribute(:expires_at, Time.at(response.expires_at))
    end
  end
end
```

I get an `undefined method 'change' for 1359936923:Fixnum` error on the final update_attribute line for :expires_at (I split it from the line above to try and figure out the issue).

I've tried both the above `update_attribute` call, and also a simple `self.expires_at = response.expires_at`, with and without `Time.at` casting but all combinations result in the same error.

The :expires_at attribute is a Timestamp datatype. I've checked the `response` variable, it contains the timestamp correctly as far as I can tell:

```
--- !ruby/object:OAuth2::AccessToken
...
expires_in: 3600
expires_at: 1360019618
options:
  :mode: :header
  :header_format: Bearer %s
  :param_name: bearer_token
...
```

Stack trace

```
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:69:in `round_usec'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:46:in `expires_at='
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:180:in `update_attribute'
app/models/identity.rb:69:in `refresh_access_token'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:30:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3108124736639590412__process_action__2258996443485139522__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:394:in `call_app!'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:356:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:77:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:219:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:175:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2408988688759615157__call__236505231918019627__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What line/file does the error point to (in rails source code)?

Comment: Sorry, the error reports to be on the second update_attribute call, for :expires_at. Without that line the action finishes successfully, but of course then my code will constantly refresh the access_token, since it won't ever get told that it's not expired.

Comment: I mean in the Ruby on Rails source code on github. To determine what is the cause of the issue. Post relevant stacktrace.

Comment: Edited question to add the stack trace

Comment: When you read the expires_at attribute from the record, do you get it as an Integer or a DateTime? If you get rid of the Time.at() call when update_attribute, does that help? Does changing the data type from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME help? Does reading the [relevant rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e9d2ad395ec2ef929d74752f3d71c80674044fbe#activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb) help?

Comment: self.column_for_attribute('expires_at').type says :datetime. With and without the Time.at() I get the same error. I'll try changing the migration to define the column as datetime rather than timestamp.

Comment: Same issue after changing the expires_at column to datetime datatype

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with it, you can turn off time zone awareness for your attribute, expires_at.

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:expires_at]
end
```

We are seeing the same issue because we have a Android app sending an Epoch time back to our website.  Turning off time zone conversion for that attribute got rid of the error and so far seems to have no ill effects on the data.  Of course, we're storing everything in UTC and so far this seems to be the only work around.

Some resources:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb