# Can't set ActiveRecord attribute - stuck as Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I set a record's timestamp attribute (`datetime` type) to `0`. I saved it (or not). I tried to set it to `0` again.

```
a = MyModel.last # => #<MyModel id:...
a.updated_at     # => Tue, 12 Mar 2013 01:36:17 UTC +00:00
a.updated_at = 0 # => 0
a.updated_at = 0
```

I got:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `change' for 0:Fixnum
```

This happened even after restarting rails and reloading the record from the database (local sqlite3). Help!

Edit: The rails console stack trace is more illuminating than the one I get from the server:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `change' for 0:Fixnum
       from /Users/nolan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:69:in `round_usec'
       from /Users/nolan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:46:in `fields_updasqliteted_at='
       from (irb):23
       from /Users/nolan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
       from /Users/nolan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
       from /Users/nolan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
       from script/rails:8:in `require'
       from script/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what's `change`? Is that an attribute on `MyModel`?

Comment: It's not something ActiveRecord calls to change a record's value...? :) Other than a migration method, I have no idea.

Comment: Just checked, this happens for other models as well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696863/undefined-method-change-for-fixnum-when-updating-timestamp-value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) to bypass Rails callbacks and validations.

For this specific case using update_column will bypass timezone and other methods callbacks used by RoR that would fail because it did not expect a FixNum.

Answer (score 0):

Since the magic columns are of type datetime, you cannot assign it a integer. If you want you can use following link:

[Ruby / Rails: convert int to time OR get time from integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871402/ruby-convert-int-to-time)

Comment: Once I do assign it an integer (by mistake), though, should it be unsettable??

Comment: If you assign it a integer it will raise the above error(the one you posted). you can assign a nil value instead of 0.

Comment: Yes, but if I *do* set it to an integer, then I can't ever change it back?

Comment: You can get help from the link i posted in my answer.

Comment: It seems I can use `update_column` to bypass the timezone magic that rails does and successfully rescue it from Fixnummery .. thanks @Gabriel Cebrian